# Angular - How to assign an Array data to another object in dynamic form

Tags: angular

I have a customer form that is generating dynamically.
The form fields are set in the **customers.ts** file:

```
public static customerForm = {
    custFormWrap: [
        {
            custFormBody: [
            {
             type: "input",
             label: "Last Name",
             name: "last_name",
            },
            {
             type: "select",
             label: "Customer type",
             name: "customer_type",
             options:[],
            },
       ]
 }
}
```

And in the component file **customers.component.ts** I have an array

```
customers: [id:1,title:"Regular",id:2,title:"premium"]
```

I can get the custFormBody in the component file, but how can I assign my array value to the options of `customer_type` select ?

There are answers on stackoverflow, but that are like assigning array A values to array B but in same file, couldn't find related this one.

Comment: do you want to assign `customers: [id:1,title:"Regular",id:2,title:"premium"]` to `options` field?

Comment: Yes, and that is in customers.ts so the dropdown on frontend will display these values.

Comment: Can u provide stackblitz? It will be much easier.

Comment: Please see here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tkcqgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing code. This is how you can assign the customers array to the dropdown options.

Just use the spread operator instead of **object.assign**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as formObj from './forms/customers';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';

  customerForm:any;

  customers= [
    {id:1, title:"Regular"},
    {id:1, title:"Premium"}
  ]

  constructor() { 
    this.customerForm = formObj.customers.customerForm;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
   
    for(let i = 0; i < this.customerForm.custFormWrap[0].custFormBody.length; i++) {
      let abc = this.customerForm.custFormWrap[0].custFormBody[i].options;
      if (abc) {
      this.customerForm.custFormWrap[0].custFormBody[i].options = [...this.customers];
      }

      console.log("final ", this.customerForm.custFormWrap[0].custFormBody[i].options);
    }  
  }
}
```

If you want to access customers array from **customers.component.ts** then import it into your app component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as formObj from '../forms/customers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customers',
  templateUrl: './customers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customers.component.css']
})
export class CustomersComponent implements OnInit {

  custData:any;

  customers: [
    {id:1, title:"Regular"},
    {id:1, title:"Premium"}
  ]

  constructor() { 
    this.custData = formObj.customers.customerForm;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.custData.custFormWrap[0].custFormBody.length; i++) {
      if(this.custData.formSteps[0].formFields[i].name == "country"){
        console.log("Testing ", this.custData.formSteps[0].formFields[i].options);

      }
    }  
  }

}
```

Also add this customersComponent into **app.module.ts** in providers array.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';
import { CustomersComponent } from './customers/customers.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent, CustomersComponent ],
  providers: [CustomersComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```